# When I try to connect to datasource in WildFly, it says Bad Handshake in error logs

Tags: java, wildfly

When I try to connect to datasource in WildFly, it says Bad Handshake in MySQL error log and WildFly says:

Failed to add datasource of sql server in wildfly [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (XNIO-1 task-2) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because my TLS version was incompatible, it was trying to use TLS 2, but my MySQL could only accept TLS 1.2. I've just started my job and the project is using legacy software, so for now were forced to use old software.

So my JDBC SQL connection was:

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE_NAME

And this didn't work, but this did work:

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE_NAME?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2

?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2 is what fixed my issue. Because my MySQL did not support TLS 2, it just didn't communicate well with my version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 14.04 ubuntu linux and for some reason I had to install mysql 5.7.34 version, then the project I was working on gave me a Badhandshake error, I fixed my problem by adding the following in **mysqld.cnf**.

```
enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

Check out the following note from MySQL DEVS.

> Note: As of MySQL 5.7.35, the TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 connection protocols
> are deprecated and support for them is subject to removal in a future
> version of MySQL. See [Deprecated TLS Protocols](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html#encrypted-connection-deprecated-protocols).